# Pass file descriptor through su -c

Tags: linux, su, file-descriptors

Given a file descriptor `fd` open in c program A, I want to start program B with `fd` open as U2. On my system (wsl2 ubuntu), `execl("/usr/bin/su", "su", suarg1, "U2");` (where suarg1 is "-c B " + toHex(fd)) seems to work, and I can access the file descriptor in B by parsing the first argument. However, I couldn't find anything about su keeping file descriptors open in any documentation, and I don't want to rely in behaviour that could change at any time. So, is there any reason why this will always work? Or if this really is up to the implementation, how could I achieve something similar that in a way that is documented to work?

Edit:
It seems I wasn't clear enough. Exec's documentation mentions that it keeps file descriptors open, however I couldn't find anything like that in su's documentation. Thus, I am not sure if I can trust that it will not close them. I did try, and it did work, but I wanted either

- some confirmation that it can be trusted to work on any Linux and in any situation, or
- some alternative way to pass `fd` from A to B that *is* documented to work

Simply keeping `fd` open would be preferable, but reliability is more important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is a side effect of `execl()`. It replaces the current process image with a new one. It does not close currently opened files and the replacement inherits them. This is done primarily for a new process to get access to stdin/stdout/stderr, but no one prevents you from passing some other files to the replacement.

Comment: I knew about exec not closing file descriptors, but execl calls su first, which presumably has to interact with files (e.g. to check the password), thus making me unsure that it will ALWAYS preserve file descriptors, and if yes, why. (for example, what does it do if there are already 1024 files open?)

Comment: Note that `execve()` does close the fds marked with the close-on-exec flag.